# Inside CGI.pm,how does thingies like END_OF_FUNC work?

Tags: perl

```
3643 '_compile_all' => <<'END_OF_FUNC',
3644 sub _compile_all {
3645     foreach (@_) {
3646         next if defined(&$_);
3647         $AUTOLOAD = "CGI::$_";
3648         _compile();
3649     }
3650 }
3651 END_OF_FUNC
3652
3653 );
3654 END_OF_AUTOLOAD
3655 ;
```

How does `END_OF_FUNC` and `END_OF_AUTOLOAD` work here?

Answer (score 3):

That is [here-doc syntax](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#%3c%3cEOF), it is just a way of writing strings.

Comment: it should separete with `;`,why `,` is used here?

Comment: Learning: it is as if everything from the line after the << up to the end mark were a string where the << is, but you can have other things on the first line that count as being after the interpolated string.  You can even have multiple << on the same line.

Comment: Compare `print <<TAG, "foo";` and `print <<TAG;`.  Or `print <<TAG x 2;`

Answer (score 1):

It's part of the nearly-obsolete `AutoLoader` mechanism, which tries to save a tiny amount of time by only defining functions when they're first referenced. It's preserved in `CGI` primarily for compatibility reasons; there's no good reason to write any new code this way.